# No Edit option for my application created contacts exported to native contacts in Phonebook

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts, android-syncadapter

I am working on an application which allows you to create a contact in the app and you can export it to native contacts DB using contact provider and also i am syncing my contacts to a server using my app.

I am using SyncAdapter to implement the 2 way contact sync.I have created an account with `AccountName` and `AccountType` using an `AuthenticatorService`

```
public class AuthenticationService extends Service {

    private Authenticator mAuthenticator;

    public AuthenticationService() {
        mAuthenticator = new Authenticator(this);
    }


    public class Authenticator extends AbstractAccountAuthenticator {
        // Simple constructor
        public Authenticator(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }
        @Override
        public Bundle editProperties(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, String accountType) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Bundle addAccount(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, String accountType, String authTokenType, String[] requiredFeatures, Bundle options) throws NetworkErrorException {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Bundle confirmCredentials(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Account account, Bundle options) throws NetworkErrorException {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Bundle getAuthToken(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Account account, String authTokenType, Bundle options) throws NetworkErrorException {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public String getAuthTokenLabel(String authTokenType) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Bundle updateCredentials(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Account account, String authTokenType, Bundle options) throws NetworkErrorException {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Bundle hasFeatures(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Account account, String[] features) throws NetworkErrorException {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mAuthenticator.getIBinder();
    }
}
```

Below is my `authenticator.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<account-authenticator
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accountType="com.contacts.example"
    android:icon="@drawable/ico_reply_all_svg"
    android:smallIcon="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
    android:label="@string/app_name"/>
```

Below is my `ContactSyncAdapterService`

```
public class ContactSyncService extends Service {

    private static SyncAdapterImpl sSyncAdapter = null;
    private static final Object sSyncAdapterLock = new Object();
    private static Context mContext;
    private static ContentResolver cr;

    private static class SyncAdapterImpl extends AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter {


        public SyncAdapterImpl(Context context,ContentResolver c) {
            super(context, true);
            mContext = context;
            cr = c;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPerformSync(Account account, Bundle extras, String authority, ContentProviderClient provider, SyncResult syncResult) {
            Log.d("TEST", "onPerformSync Called");
            // run sync with server
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        synchronized (sSyncAdapterLock) {
            if(sSyncAdapter == null) {
                sSyncAdapter = new SyncAdapterImpl(getApplicationContext(), getContentResolver());
            }
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return sSyncAdapter.getSyncAdapterBinder();
    }
}
```

and `syncadapter.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sync-adapter
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:contentAuthority="com.android.contacts"
    android:accountType="com.contacts.example"
    android:userVisible="true"
    android:supportsUploading="true"
    android:allowParallelSyncs="false"
    android:isAlwaysSyncable="true"/>
```

Below is how i am exporting my contacts to native contacts database with my `accountName` and `accountType`

```
public void addContact() {

        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops =
                new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

        int rawContactInsertIndex = ops.size();
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, "com.contacts.example")
                .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, "dummyaccount1")
                .withValue(RawContacts.RAW_CONTACT_IS_READ_ONLY, "0")
                .build());

        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
                .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, "DoomsDay2")
                .withValue(Data.IS_READ_ONLY, 0")
                .build());
        try {
            getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Account creation code is below :

```
public static Account CreateSyncAccount(Context context) {

        public static final String ACCOUNT_TYPE = "com.contacts.example";
        // The account name
        public static final String ACCOUNT_NAME = "dummyaccount1";
        // Create the account type and default account
        Account newAccount = new Account(
                ACCOUNT_NAME, ACCOUNT_TYPE);
        // Get an instance of the Android account manager
        AccountManager accountManager =
                (AccountManager) context.getSystemService(
                        ACCOUNT_SERVICE);
        /*
         * Add the account and account type, no password or user data
         * If successful, return the Account object, otherwise report an error.
         */
        if (accountManager.addAccountExplicitly(newAccount, null, null)) {
            /*
             * If you don't set android:syncable="true" in
             * in your <provider> element in the manifest,
             * then call context.setIsSyncable(account, AUTHORITY, 1)
             * here.
             */
        } else {
            /*
             * The account exists or some other error occurred. Log this, report it,
             * or handle it internally.
             */
        }
        return newAccount;
    }
```

Below is the problem in facing :

1. The exported contact is visible in the native contacts app. But i am not able to edit those contact using native contact app. Simply there is no option to edit. It say they are read only.
2. I want to edit these contact in the native app and run syncadapter so that i can fetch these modified contact back to my app and hence to server.
3. Is it OEMs specific? I tried on many different devices but behaviour is same.
4. Is this even possible ? We can edit only those Account contacts which are added by the device using Add Account(like we add for google contacts)?

Please help me solve this!! Thanks in advance.

Comment: judging from your other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56578688/how-to-define-contactsaccounttype-for-a-server-like-exchange-to-allow-user-to-ed i assume you've solved this?

Comment: Hi @marmor, yes could you please answer that question. Still stuck on that.